# Restsharp is returning invalid response

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have run into an issue with Restsharp where the response is coming back invalid. The problem seems to only appear when the amount of data returned is large.

I am using the following code to get the response from RestSharp. Since I know the actual http response is OK (by using Fiddler) I am a bit stuck on what is going on here. Is the response simply too large? It is returning 450 results with 4 values each.

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

The first two brackets are correct. Each object returned should have 4 values, but at some point it just breaks.

```
"Id": 2143893
        }, {
            "Country": null,
            "CrmId": "29084241146",
            "Name": "Sara Johnsen1",
            "Id": 2143894
        }, {
            "Country": null,
            "CrmId": "19065337870",
            "Name": "Sara Andersen68",
            "Id": 2143895
        }, {
            "Country": null,
            "CrmId": "08019044271",
            "Name": "test",
            "Id"...489 ","
            Name ":"
            Magnus Jensen102 ","
            Id ":2143927},{"
            Country ":null,"
            CrmId ":"
            11053848682 ","
```

This is how it should look like:

```
 },
  {  
     "Country":null,
     "CrmId":"04075544842",
     "Name": "Sara Andersen68",
     "Id":2146236
  },
  {  
     "Country":null,
     "CrmId":"29114839645",
     "Name": "Magnus Andersen21",
     "Id":2146237
  },
  {  
     "Country":null,
     "CrmId":"27045633905",
     "Name": "Tom Kato21",
     "Id":2146238
  },
  {  
     "Country":null,
     "CrmId":"16045532686",
     "Name": "Ole Jensen94",
     "Id":2146239
  }
```

I use JsonLint to check the result which give the following error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1056:
...e": "test",              "Id"...489 ","              Name 
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'
```

When using Fiddler to inspect the actual result returned by the web service the result is perfect, so it is somewhere within RestSharp the error occurs.

Comment: Could you show the original (Fiddler)  results as well? Maybe theres something off. :)

Comment: I added a sample of how it looks from Fiddler, however after testing further with using filters to retrieve different data sets I am confident this is not data related. The error always comes when retrieving more than 400 objects for some reason no matter which objects it is.